# why wont python-pip install matplotlib work?

Tags: 16.04, python-2.7

I just installed kubuntu 16.04 on my computer and started to install some python packages but some of them wont install. the command I type in is

```
pip install matplotlib
```

and it does not work. I get the following error message

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-H6XoGm/matplotlib/
```

I am running python 2.7.12 and I have updated python-pip.

Comment: That's unlikely the only error message you saw. Can you add all the error messages you saw?

Comment: I didn't get any other errors. I did see `freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype2 (ft2build.h)
                            could not be found.  You may need to install the
                            development package.]
                       png: no  [pkg-config information for 'libpng' could not
                            be found.]` that it is missing these dependences

Comment: Well, that's the problem: you don't have all the dependencies installed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, you are missing some of the dependencies that `matplotlib` requires, namely `libpng-dev` and `libfreetype6-dev`. Install these dependencies by running:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libpng-dev libfreetype6-dev
```